# A simple Game of Pig

Tags: python-3.x, dice

The code I have for the game runs just fine, but I'm having trouble getting the game to end when one person reaches at least 100 points.

```
def dont_Be_Greedy(turn):
points = 0
keepPlaying = 121
print('Lets start!')
input('Press enter to roll')
while keepPlaying == 121:
    roll = roll_Dice()
    print('You rolled a ' + str(roll))
    if roll == 1:
        points = 0 * roll
        keepPlaying = 110
        enter = input('Your turn is over. Next player.')
    elif roll > 1:
        points += roll
        print('your total is', points)
        passPlay = input('Do you want to keep playing or pass?'
                         '\ntype pass or play. ')                                                          
        if passPlay == 'play':
            keepPlaying = 121
        else:
            keepPlaying = 110
            enter = input('Your turn is over. Next player.')        
return points


player1 = 0
player2 = 0
while player1 < 100 and player2 < 100:
    print('Player 1 points are: ' + str(player1))
    print('Player 2 points are: ' + str(player2))
    gameOn = dont_Be_Greedy(1)
    player1 += gameOn
    print('Player 1 points are: ' + str(player1))
    print('Player 2 points are: ' + str(player2))
    gameOn = dont_Be_Greedy(2)
    player2 += gameOn
    if player1 >= 100:
         print('Player 1 is the winner!')
    elif player2 >= 100:
         print('Player 2 is the winner!')
```

Instead of the program stopping when one player reaches 100, it lets them continue their turn. After they pass their turn, it lets the next player start rolling until they pass or roll one then the program stops and states the winner (person with the higher of the two scores).
I'm not sure where the problem is.

EDIT: I added `dont_Be_Greedy` I tried moving the `if` and `elif` statements just below the loop and the program stops without printing the winner.

Comment: So, the obvious question: is the `print` statement executed (Player 1/2 is the winner!)?

Comment: I think your problem is with `dont_Be_Greedy()`. Make sure that it stops on 100.

Comment: @UnholySheep I'm not sure I understand your question.

Comment: @Bharel I originally thought it would be there but it doesn't keep track the total score.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like your problem lies with `dont_Be_Greedy()`.

It doesn't stop when it reaches 100.